# Flash movie not displayed on other PC

Tags: c++, flash, mfc, visual-studio-2005, activex

I am developing an application using C++ and MFC that shall display an swf file. I use Shockwave Flash Object control found in VS2005, set Movie property to C:\test.swf and it displays the movie fine on my pc. When I move my program to another pc, (first i create a deployment project and create setup, then i install my software on other PC in order to have all required dll files and stuff on second pc) i double click the application and instead of flash movie i see an empty space. When I right click to that space, I see "movie not loaded". Please note that I have c:\test.swf (same file) on the other PC as well.

Why can't I display flash on the other PC?

note: flash player is installed on other pc

Comment: How could anyone possibly know why with the little information that you gave? You're basically asking, "Why isn't my program working on the other machine?" Do some debugging; do some print logging. Find out the reason your program isn't loading the SWF file. Could it not find the file, or could it not process it?

Comment: What am I supposed to do, copy and paste the whole source code here? I've tried to ask without bloating, no unnecessary details. It is not possible to debug on the other machine since there I don't have vs, only executable. and due to its configuration I cannot install vs. there is nothing to print log, bcoz it is one dialogue with one flash control. and yes, i am basically asking because this website is one where you ask and seek for the answer. if any part of the question is unclear, comment it and i will elaborate. but if you do not want to help but only bash, i will not comment.

Comment: My point is that you haven't given us enough information for us to diagnose anything. The SFO ActiveX control must have some diagnostic functionality in the event of errors. Do those tell you if the control couldn't find the file or found it to have a malformed format? Also, what version of Flash do you have installed on the machines.

Comment: I had been looking for an event for finding the problem, but unfortunately sfo does not seem to support events in case of errors. there are only 4 events supported (FlashCall, FSCommand, OnProgress, OnReadyStateChange). However I am not sure when exactly they are triggered. That's why I could not find a way to determine the cause if it is not finding file or if it is wrong file format. Any ideas?

Comment: Another thing is, when I try to clean the Movie property, I fail. I cannot leave that property blank, vs sets to previous value when I clear it. Thats why I cannot leave it blank and call LoadMovie to see if it fails or not. I thought maybe I can find the error that way, but since Movie property cannot be unset, i can't do it either

Answer (score 0):

Try writing console-logging into your source-code to output some debugging information for you. Compile your project and then place this executable on the other machine.

With the information we have, we can't answer this question appropriately for you, but here is at least a good suggestion.

Comment: The problem is there is almost no source code to log. Actually, there is no source code to log. I have just dragged and dropped the control on dialogue, set the property "Movie" on properties pane, and it works on my PC. I'd been searching whole solution for a clue where the control is created, movie is loaded, etc.. but i cannot find any place. The only piece of code is its declaration and  DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_SHOCKWAVEFLASH1, m_flashPlayer);